# Rounding the float value to the nearest 9

Tags: python, floating-point

eg. 0.17 --> 0.19 and 3.52 -->3.49

Comment: What do you mean by "the nearest 9", do you mean the nearest value that has two decimal places and ends in `9` or something else? What would `0.8` "round" to?

Comment: for example  0.80 --> 0.79 and 2.00 --> 1.99

considering two decimal point

Comment: Bit ugly but this works I think `round(x + 0.01, 1) - 0.01` where `x` is your float

Comment: What shall `0.14`, `0.04`, `0.03`, or `0.00` round to?

Comment: this is applicable to the price of product so price can not be the negative.
0.14 -- > 0.19, 
0.04 --> 0.09, 
0.03 --> 0.0,
0.0 -->0.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.